# How to get all the date of last one month

Tags: objective-c

i want to get all the dates from yesterday date to one month..
like today is 19 may, so i need all the date from 18 may to 18 April.
please help.

Comment: What have to done to solve this yourself?

Comment: i have get the yesterday date. like 18 and the last day will b 17 and then i get the last month like april then i calculate all the day of april now i want to maintain this..give yours logic

Comment: thats why i need help friend, please give the solution...i am also trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code.It works.

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"Current Date = %@", currentDate);

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [NSDateComponents new];
dateComponents.month = -1;

NSDate *currentDatePlus1Month = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:currentDate options:0];

NSLog(@"Date = %@", currentDatePlus1Month );

NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *days = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
NSMutableArray* arr =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSInteger dayCount = 0;
while ( TRUE ) {
    [days setDay: ++dayCount];
    NSDate *date = [gregorianCalendar dateByAddingComponents: days toDate: currentDatePlus1Month options: 0];
    if ( [date compare: currentDate] == NSOrderedAscending ){
        [arr addObject:date];

    }
    if([[arr lastObject] isEqual:[currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*60*24*1]])
    {
        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)arr.count);
        break;

    }
    // Do something with date like add it to an array, etc.
}
```

if you find all dates you can remove count and get all dates in array.

Comment: thank you..it works...if i want the date from tomorrow to next month..like 20 may to 20 june..how to do? @user5598592

Comment: Some days don't have 24 hours. Don't use `60*60*24`.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, I think you should have an `Array` holding all those dates. I'll write pseudocode about the logic here.

```
INIT dateArray
NSDate pastDate = (today).yesterday
NSDate lastMonth = pastDate.lastMonth()
WHILE pastDate > lastMonth // pastDate is after lastMonth
    dateArray.add(pastDate)
    pastDate = pastDate.yesterday
END WHILE
```

About how to turn this pseudocode into real code is another story (this would be quite long). Hope this help.

PS: If you'd like Objective-C solution, please comment. I'll take my time write it for you ;)

Comment: please give it to me the objc solution...if you can give your time.. thank you so much @Eddie